# Biblatex and the library field

Tags: biblatex

I have many Bibtex database files which I am updating to `biblatex` format.  In BibTeX I created a custom library field which appeared at the end of my bibliographic entry in small capitals.  I did this by creating a new bibliographystyle.

All I want to do is get the library field to appear at the end of every reference where it occurs.  I know that it is probably somewhere in the 262 page manual, but to be frank, even for someone who has been using LaTeX and BibTeX for almost 30 years, the manual is pretty indigestible (oh for a good "quick start" guide!). Any pointers to how I can do this quickly and easily would be welcome.

I am using the `authoryear` style.

Comment: You mean `style=authoryear`? The easiest way would be to put the information in the `addendum` field or use a Sourcemap (requires Biber, not BibTeX) to map your `library` field to the `addendum` field.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  As _this_ file is quite small the "quick fix" is just to copy everything into the addendum field.  I will check out Sourcemap when I have a bit more time.

Comment: OT here, but the problem with a 'quick start' guide is always that different people have different ideas of what should be in it. Here, I don't think manipulating custom fields really would feature: it's an 'advanced' effect.

Answer (score 3):

With the standard styles you can just add a call to print the `library` field directly into the macro `addendum+pubstate`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{library}{\textsc{call number}\addcolon\space#1}
\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{library}}
```

MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{pennington1981,
  editor =       {Pennington, Kenneth},
  title =        {Johannis {Teutonici} apparatus glossarum in
                  {Compilationem} tertiam},
  date =         1981,
  volume =       1,
  number =       3,
  series =       {Monumenta iuris canonici, Series A: Corpus glossatorum},
  location =     {Rome},
  publisher =    {Biblioteca apostolica vaticana},
  library =      {BV 104 .M81 ser.A v.3 t.1},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{library}{\textsc{call number}\addcolon\space#1}
\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{library}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

For (future) reference, this sort of sourcemapping is fairly straightforward. Biber is required, however.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{pennington1981,
  editor =       {Pennington, Kenneth},
  title =        {Johannis {Teutonici} apparatus glossarum in
                  {Compilationem} tertiam},
  date =         1981,
  volume =       1,
  number =       3,
  series =       {Monumenta iuris canonici, Series A: Corpus glossatorum},
  location =     {Rome},
  publisher =    {Biblioteca apostolica vaticana},
  library =      {BV 104 .M81 ser.A v.3 t.1},
}


\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
       \step[fieldsource=library,]
       \step[fieldset=addendum, fieldvalue={\textsc{call number:}~}]
       \step[fieldset=addendum, origfieldval, append]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\section{Publications}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```